# Sort objects in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, orm

I get some objects out of SQL tables in CakePHP 3.0 with this line :

```
$query = $this->Categories->find()
    ->contain('Subcategories.Texts.Tags.TagTypes');
```

But if I edit a Text entry, the display order change. How can I sort the texts by ID ? I tried this :

```
    $query = $this->Categories->find()
        ->contain('Subcategories.Texts.Tags.TagTypes', 
            ['order'=>[
                'Categories.id'=>'ASC', 
                'Subcategories.id'=>'ASC', 
                'Texts.id'=>'ASC'
            ]]);
```

As expected I get an object similar to

```
[
    'name' => 'category_name', 
    'subcategories'=> [
        [
            'name'=>'subcategory_name', 
            'texts'=>[
                 [
                     'content'=>'text_content'
                 ]
            ]
       ]
    ]
]
```

But the order texts are stored in this structure changes according to their last edit date.

Edit :
I tried this

```
$query = $this->Categories->find()->contain('Subcategories.Texts.Tags.TagTypes',
        ['strategy'=>'select',
        'queryBuilder'=>function($q)
        {return $q->order(['Texts.id'=>'ASC']);}
        ]);
```

How can I get them ordered by ID ?

Comment: What are the associations between all these tables? Have you tried this:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#changing-fetching-strategies

Comment: A Tag hasOne TaType and belongTo a Text that belongTo a Subcategory that belongTo a Category.